# How to predict using Keras and a generator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a custom generator I have successfully used to train a Keras model. I've tried to modify it to use it for predicting:

```
def image_gen(ws):

    filenames = glob(f'{ws}/*.h5')

    for filename in filenames:
        X = process(filename)

        yield X
```

I'm calling model.predict like so:

```
filenames = glob(f'{ws}/run/*.h5')

i = 0
while True:
    for results in model.predict(image_gen(ws=f'{ws}/run'),
                                  callbacks=callbacks,
                                  workers=1,
                                  steps=10,
                                  verbose=1):

        np.save(filenames[i]), results)
        i += 1
```

This, however, only predicts on the same first set of 10 images over and over again. Without the `while true:` loop, I just get the first 10 images and then it stops altogether.

How do I get `model.predict` to process all my files?

Comment: Have you tried to change the argument steps = 10?

Comment: Sure, that changes how many images it processes. If I change it to 100, I get 100 images and then fitting stops or repeats. It changes how many are processed at a time, but not how many total.